# Is there a way to prevent Django from trimming leading white space in a text field?

Tags: django, whitespace, psql

Is there a way to prevent Django from trimming leading white space in `models.TextField`? I've been scouring the docs and haven't found anything. The database I'm using is PSQL. Any guidance would be appreciated.

An answer made me aware there is a solution using forms. As of right now, I don't use forms:

```py
class Song(models.Model):
    """
    Fields that are displayed on the Song screeen
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default="")
    creator = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lyrics = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    pulled_lyrics = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    chords = models.TextField(default="", blank=True)
    strumming_pattern = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="", blank=True)

    """
    Additional information used to determine where to display the song
    """
    public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_favourite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```py
class SongViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SongSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Sets queryset to be songs owned by user
        This makes it so that a user can only manipulate their own songs
        """
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return []

        user = self.request.user
        qs = Song.objects.all()
        if user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        else:
            return qs.filter(creator=user)
    
    def create(self, request):
        """
        Create user with given request body
        """
        try:
            song = Song.objects.create(creator=request.user, **request.data)
        except:
            return Response('The provided data was of an invalid form.', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        song_serializer = SongSerializer(song)
        return Response(song_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

JS (React) code to create a new song and patch a song respectively:

```js
const response = await axios.post(
                "/api/songs/",
                {},
                {
                    withCredentials: true,
                    headers: {
                        "X-CSRFToken": getToken(),
                    },
                }
            );
```

```js
const songCopy = { ...item }
    delete songCopy["creator"];
    axios.patch(`/api/songs/${item.id}/`, songCopy, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRFToken": getToken(),
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**, you form field should set [**`strip=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip) in the form, so:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    some_field = forms.CharField(strip=False)
```

For a serializer this is quite similar, in your serializer you should set [**`trim_whitespace=False`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield):

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class SongSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    lyrics = serializers.CharField(trim_whitespace=False)
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip) says:

> If `True` (default), the value will be **stripped of leading and trailing whitespace**.

If you render the data then multiple (leading) spaces will be rendered on the webpage as one space. You can make use of `<pre>` tag as a *preformatted* text element, so:

```
{{ some_variable }}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do it with `models`? I'm not using forms in my code.

Comment: @SamLiu: exactly how are you editing your models? Can you edit the question with an example. Normally it is *not* a good idea to do processing of the request data in the view oneself: a form removes a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: @SamLiu: note that if you render data in a template, it will render the spaces, but HTML does not show multiple spaces, it will show this as a single space.

Comment: I updated my answer above. I'm using React so I don't directly render form templates.

Comment: @SamLiu: for the serializer you should set `trim_whitespace=False`, see edit.